# Android Project - IDE independent source code

Tags: git, ide, gitignore

I would like to create a git repository for my project without adding IDE specific files. I've been working with Android Studio and I've created a git repository with something like:

```
.gitignore
LICENSE.txt
README.md
app/
```

Note that app has only .java and res files.

How could I avoid, as much as possible, IDEs specific files (I know you .gitignore!) and how could I import it as new project in other IDEs without much trouble?

UPDATE: I am using gradle to build it. I would like to keep it too ...

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have a `.gitignore` that ignores the temporary and output files of your build system.

I'd recommend to head over to https://gitignore.io and let you generate the `.gitignore` suitable for your configuration.

I generated one with the keywords `eclipse`, `android` and `gradle` (https://www.gitignore.io/api/android,gradle,eclipse) and the result is this:

```
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io

### Android ###
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/
/*/build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

### Android Patch ###
gen-external-apklibs


### Gradle ###
.gradle
build/

# Ignore Gradle GUI config
gradle-app.setting

# Avoid ignoring Gradle wrapper jar file (.jar files are usually ignored)
!gradle-wrapper.jar


### Eclipse ###
*.pydevproject
.metadata
.gradle
bin/
tmp/
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.settings/
.loadpath

# Eclipse Core
.project

# External tool builders
.externalToolBuilders/

# Locally stored "Eclipse launch configurations"
*.launch

# CDT-specific
.cproject

# JDT-specific (Eclipse Java Development Tools)
.classpath

# PDT-specific
.buildpath

# sbteclipse plugin
.target

# TeXlipse plugin
.texlipse
```